# What is the difference between "beneficial" and "beneficent'?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between "beneficial" and "beneficent'? They seem to have the same meaning of "helpful".

Comment: You should specify which dictionaries you have consulted. Also, have you googled _beneficent beneficial difference_? After a quick glance, I see that _beneficent_ shares its secondary meaning with _beneficial_, but its primary one clearly differs.

Answer (score 2):

"Beneficial" refers to an object or act that has a positive effect towards something.

"Beneficent" refers to something or someone that has the quality of being beneficial, I.E., an individual who acts on something in a beneficial manner, rather than the act itself or the attribute that thing has.

Helpful is different than these words in that it references a willingness to assist or an attribute of beign in assistance.